# Access Denied when Check in document in SharePoint Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, permissions

I have set following permissions for users on my site:

- Site level: Read
- Document Library Folder: Contribute

With this permission level if user tries to check in the document inside a folder where user has to contribute permission even if it gives

> Access Denied Error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Permission level **Read** excludes the permission for a setting called "**Browse Directories**", which would be built-in in the Contribute permission level, and higher. I think that **Browse Directories** is required to check in a document.

You could try to make a special permission level which includes the possibility to browse directories, and add it with the read-level permissions, and finally assign this permission level at site-level.

To read more about permissions and permission levels, see [User permissions and permission levels](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx).

Comment: Thats right. One should create custom permission level based on their organization needs. Let the default permissions levels (Read/View?Contribute etc.) as it is.